# My project has no errors, but I found strangely errors. Can errors of TypeError's undefined functions be because of PHP, Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My project B has errors even if I didn't find errors in my whole project. It is strange.

- Bootstrap 4.0.0 Beta uses jQuery 3.2.1
- UniteGallery uses jQuery 11.0
- jQuery.nicescroll uses jQuery 2

I use only jQuery 3. I do not want to use several versions of jQuery because it is not necessary.

I tested two plugins jQuery.nicescroll and UniteGallery on the project A, using only jQuery 3 and `$variables` and everything worked without errors.

On my project B, using only jQuery 3 and all `define("", "");`, I got errors of TypeError's undefined functions that Chrome and Safari told in the console. I reviewed the whole project and I didn't find any error. I scanned the project, using linter and there are no errors.

You can see the libraries order and there is no error in this order or in these scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/unitegallery.js'></script>   
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/ug-theme-tiles.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("html").niceScroll({
    cursorwidth: 12,
    cursoropacitymin: 0.5,
    cursorcolor: '#ff8a80',
    cursorborder: 'none',
    cursorborderradius: 10,
    autohidemode: 'leave',
    horizrailenabled:false
  }); 

  $("#mc-scroll").niceScroll({
    cursorborderradius: 3, 
    cursorcolor:"#1a237e", 
    cursoropacitymin: 0, 
    cursorwidth: "3px", 
    railpadding: { top: 0, left: 0 }
  });

  $("#fotogaleria").unitegallery();

});
</script>
```

In the file `index.php` and thee is no error there.

```
<body>

  <?php include("cabecalho.php") ?>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">          
          <?php include("fotogaleria.php") ?>          
        </div>
      </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
  </div> <!-- wrapper -->  

  <?php include("rodape.php") ?>

</body>
</html>
```

In the file `fotogaleria.php` which is included inside the file `index.php`:

```
<div id="fotogaleria" style="display:none;">
   <a href="imagens/noivos/noivos1.jpg">
     <img alt="<?php echo _alt_novios1 ?>"
     src="imagens/noivos/noivos1.jpg"
     data-image="imagens/noivos/noivos1.jpg"
     data-description="<?php echo _alt_novios1 ?>"
     style="display:none">
   </a>           
</div>
```

There are the errors:

- In the case of jQuery.nicescroll, but the functions codes are correct:

`TypeError: self.autohidedom.stop is not a function. (In 'self.autohidedom.stop()', 'self.autohidedom.stop' is undefined)`

- In the car of UniteGallery:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.easing["swing"]')`

The error showed the code line of UniteGallery:

```
(function(factory) { if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) { define(["jquery"], function($) { return factory($) }) } else if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") { exports = factory(require("jquery")) } else { factory(jQuery) } })(function($) { $.easing["jswing"] = $.easing["swing"]; var pow = Math.pow,
```

- In the case of jQuery which is caused by UniteGallery:

`TypeError: $("#fotogaleria").unitegallery is not a function. (In '$("#fotogaleria").unitegallery()', '$("#fotogaleria").unitegallery' is undefined)`

And the jQuery code line showed:

```
jQuery.readyException = function(error) {
​    window.setTimeout(function() {
​        throw error;
​    });
};
```

I couldn't figure the real cause of these errors.

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what the error is.

Comment: Looks like you also need to include easing plugin and possibly won't be able to use jquery 3 or need to include migration plugin to see if all methods used  in plugins are available in jquery 3

Comment: In the debugger, the errors are the same, @SLaks

Comment: Let me understand. including the jQuery 3 and the plugins in the index.php instead?

Comment: I have just tested, the errors are the same.

Comment: I switched jQuery 3 to jQuery 11 and the UniteGallery and nicescroll appeared normally, but Bootstrap 4 requires jQuery 3.